# Logging framework for .NET that supports multiple applications writing to the the same rolling log file?

Tags: .net, logging

I have a console application that writes to a rolling log file.  The problem is that application can be called by several processes and there's a chance that it will be called simultaneously.  The application writes to one log file.  I'm currently investigating using log4net with the MinimalLock setting:

```
<lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender+MinimalLock" />
```

but I've read that issues can arise if a logging message from one instance causes a roll over while another instance is trying to write to the same file.

Is there another framework that supports this behaviour, or perhaps a suitable workaround?

Answer (score 1):

try `<lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+InterProcessLock"`

Now following code will be thread safe because you will create a logger static class to log information.

```
public static class Logger
{
    private static readonly Object obj = new Object();

    private static ILog _appLog = null;
    static Logger()
    {
        XmlConfigurator.Configure();
    }

    public static void Log(string loggername)
    {
        lock (obj)
        {
            _appLog = LogManager.GetLogger(loggername);
            _appLog.Error(....);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: From the FAQ: "RollingFileAppender completely ignores the locking model when rolling files, rolling files is simply not compatible with this scenario."